# Include variable definitions in multiple views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a number of views I have the following kind of code:

```
<% compute a number of variables %>

Do something with those variables to layout and configure HTML elements.
```

I'm drying to dry up my views.  That first part where I compute the values for the variables is used in a number of different views.  I would like to be able to pull it out into another file and use it in each view that needs it so that I only have to change it in one place.  If I pull it into its own partial and then render that partial in another view, the variables are not defined in the view.  To be more specific:

```
<% 
top = 0
link.siblings_before.each do |sibling|
   top = top + compute_top(sibling)
end
%>

<div style="position:absolute;top:<%= top %>px"><%= link.name %></div>
```

I want to be able to use the computation of top in more than one view without having to cut and paste the ruby code into each view.

Comment: Create a helper method instead. Looping through each seems really wasteful to. Whatever it is you are trying to achieve you can probably do it by using a index or just better CSS.

Comment: Well the whole thing is actually a lot more complex than that.  I have a number of objects on screen that need to be redrawn based on user interactions.   Sometimes these variables are used in a js.erb to update the css of existing objects and sometimes these variables are used to configure a new object being added through an html.erb.

Comment: When you declare a partial to render you can also set the local variables to send to it. 

<%= render 'shared/_multi_purpose_partial', locals: { generic_local_variable: @whatever_local_variable } %>

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding logic in your views.

You can define a `before_filter` in your controller and enabled it for multiple actions that you need them for.

Those variables defined in your before filter will be available in those views and you keep your views clear at the same time.

Comment: s/variables/instance variables/